# Changed an old Led light to pendant and it keeps shorting

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I recently just replaced an old LED ceiling light with a simple pendant and as soon as I switch it on it shorts.

I've made sure that I kept everything in place but as soon as I switch it on, POP it trips.

Pictures are attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE7Sw.jpg, any help would be great.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not sure but it looks like black wires going to the neutral. here in the U.S. black is for hot.

Comment: Seeing no whites, blues and green/yellow, I'd say blue is neutral and green/yellow is safety earth.  Nothing seems obviously wrong except the red wires are a big mess.  Is the circuit breaker (that trips) a GFCI, or in the UK, an RCD?

Comment: @EdBeal: In UK old colours, black is neutral and red is live (hot). EU colours are brown and blue respectively and are now used in UK for fixed wiring as well as for flexible lamp-cords and appliance cords.

Comment: *"I kept everything in place but as soon as I switch it on, POP it trips."* - if following RedGrittyBrick's answer does not get you past this, it's perhaps time to call an electrician. Assuming it did not trip before you rewired it, you only *think* you kept everything in place, but have evidence suggesting otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need all those floating connector blocks, there are enough positions on the backplate for loop-in, loop-out, switch and pendant.

The pendant should be connected to the outermost positions and looped through the cord grips.

Your wires to the switch probably include a red permanent-live and a black switched live which should be marked with red tape and connected at the double position connector.

[image]

In the above diagram, A is loop-in from prior ceiling-rose (or from consumer unit), B is loop-out to next ceiling rose and C is to/from switch. Typically all wires are 1mm² or 1.5mm² twin & earth with green/yellow sleeving added to the bare earth wires.

Note that I think most UK electricians wire the wires from the switch cable (C) in the other way than that shown in this diagram, they connect the red to position 3 and the black (with red tape) to position 2. That's the way I, as a mere home-owner, wire these fittings.

[image]
<sup>*Photo - own work, © RedGrittyBrick. Licence: [Creative-Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)*</sup>

At the top are three 1.5 mm² Twin&Earth cables with the 2004 colours (blue neutral, brown line/live) the bare circuit protective conductor (CPC or Earth) in the cable is covered by a green/yellow sheath when terminated.

From left to right these are feed-in, feed-out and switch. The blue from the switch is covered in red tape (probably should be brown?) to indicate switched-live.

The flex to the pendant lamp is looped around the strain relief.

---

Could it be that in your case, the black switched-live is not marked with red tape and has been connected with the other blacks - this would short the circuit when the switch is turned on